# Missing header tiffio.h installing Pillow on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, pip, mezzanine, libtiff, python-imaging-library

When trying to install Pillow using PIP, I get this include error:

```
μ ~: pip install pillow
...
libImaging/TiffDecode.h:10:10: fatal error: 'tiffio.h' file not found

#include <tiffio.h>

         ^

1 error generated.

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this? I'm on OS X 10.9 and have previously been able to build Pillow on this computer.

**Update:** Note that I have `tiffio.h` on my machine at `/usr/local/include/tiffio.h`. After setting that directory to the C include path, I am able to successfully compile Pillow.

```
μ ~: C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/include
μ ~: pip install pillow
Downloading/unpacking pillow
...
Successfully installed pillow
Cleaning up...
```

Is this how it's supposed to be done, or is there something wrong with my machine or the installation package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced the same issue and got it solved by installing [libtiff](http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/libtiff.html) using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install libtiff
```

Comment: you may also have an outdated version, in which case you'll want `brew upgrade libtiff`

Comment: thanks! this helped me solve installing R's tidyverse on MacOS 14.3